# MongoDB build on Lion and MacPorts

Tags: mongodb, macports, osx-lion

So there seems to be an issue with util/processinfo_darwin.cpp as described in [MacPorts trac](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/30263)

I'm stuggling to find the file to edit? any help?

Comment: Have you tried using [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) to install MongoDB?

Comment: found a good solution on the macports trac https://trac.macports.org/ticket/30263#comment:4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from here: https://svn.macports.org/ticket/30263 as Jan mentioned above

```
sudo port clean mongodb
sudo port extract mongodb
cd $(port work mongodb)/mongodb*
sudo curl -O https://jira.mongodb.org/secure/attachment/12395/lion.patch
sudo patch -p1 < lion.patch
cd
sudo port install mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, Homebrew MongoDB on Lion seems to be working well.

I'd suggest that if you are having an issue with building on the new distribution, you should definitely open a ticket on the [MongoDB JIRA](http://jira.mongodb.org) so that we can track down and fix any issues on our end.

Comment: No need. I did find a ticket on the MacPorts site that explained and resolved the issue. Tx.